# jquery target link click event

Tags: jquery, events, hyperlink, click, target

i create some links on the fly ...

```
 $('input[name="iplus"]').click(function() {  
    $(ol).append("<a href='#' title='delposition' class='beschr-"+($("#billsumary ol>li").length+1)+"'>l&ouml;schen</a>");  
});
```

now I like to target each created link like $('a[title='delposition']') and assign a click-event like:

```
$("a[title='delposition']").click(function() {
 alert("Link klicked ...");
});
```

...but this dont do it?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method of JQuery should do the trick:

```
$("a[title='delposition']").live('click', function() {
 alert("Link klicked ...");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the click handler when you create the element, like this this:

```
$('input[name="iplus"]').click(function() {  
  $("<a href='#' title='delposition' class='beschr-"+($("#billsumary ol>li").length+1)+"'>l&ouml;schen</a>")
  .click(function() {
    alert("clicked on");
  }).appendTo(ol);  
});
```

This builds the element, adds a click handler, then appends it to the `ol` object like your original code.